# magento 1.8 static block in widget not showing?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I have created simple static block and trying to show it through widget inside Left Column but its not showing. In fact any static block is not working through widget. I have created magento theme in 1.9 with static blocks it was working fine now I'm deploying it to magento 1.8 any reasons ?

I'm attaching it in Left Column,

cms->widgets creating new instance

type:cms static block;

design: customTheme/default (i have also tried with base/default, default/default )

Widget Instance Title:left-block

Assign to Store Views: All Store Views;

sort order:1

Add Layout Update:

Display On:Non-Anchor Categories

Block Reference:Left Column

widget option: Left Block